# What word can be used to translate "uploader"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, informática

In Spanish, the very term upload has various usages in various countries. Where I'm from, we use the term "subir" and "bajar" for "upload" and "download". However, I would never say "subidor" or "bajador". Google Translate suggests "cargador", but that seems like an inadequate choice.

What word can/should be used to translate this term?

Comment: Is this in a computer context?  I remember attending a conference in Barcelona.  One of the presenters was from Colombia so it was suggested that he presented in Spanish (they forgot that some of the audience did not speak Spanish).  He mixed loads of English computer terms into his Spanish and the audience found it so weird that they preferred him to switch back to English.

Comment: Yes, in a computer/internet context, downloading/uploading files. I can imagine! Many people find it preferable to just use the English terms in many cases.

Comment: It seems that the Latin Americans preferred to use the English terms but the Europeans did not.  My point was that your answer might differ depending on where you want to use it.  The story is quite old so I am not sure whether it still applies.

Comment: The terms _cargar_ and _descargar_ do exist with the required verbal meaning so _cargador_ might work.

Comment: Why don't you define the term in your question? An uploader is **a program** that helps a person upload something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A search on [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=uploader) shows that, in most of the cases, no single word is used to translate "uploader".

If you are referring to a *program* that uploads files, expressions like *utilidad/programa/herramienta de subida de archivos* are common (or *herramienta de upload*, which is used in some Latin American countries but not in Spain).

Some [programs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SS8JB4/com.ibm.wbpm.ref.doc/topics/spk_content_bpm_file_uploader.html) do use the word *cargador*, but the DLE does not include this meaning of the word [cargador](https://dle.rae.es/cargador).

If you are referring to a *person* that uploads files, I have not found any example of a single word used for this in Spanish. Expressions like *la persona que ha subido el archivo* are used often, or other terms that are only valid in some cases like *autor*, or *publicador*.

Comment: Publicador is a great choice for this context, thank you! (I'm going to add "(uploader)" beside it just to make it clear).

Answer (score 0):

Existen diversas traducciones según el uso/contexto.
http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=upload

**cargar, subir**
Transferir datos o archivos desde un ordenador local, por lo general sobre un módem o red, hacia Internet, un BBS, o un servicio en línea, para almacenarlo en un ordenador remoto. Existe la norma no escrita de que la red está situada sobre nosotros, por eso, cuando traemos información de la red se habla de bajar, mientras que si mandamos información a la red se habla de subir.